# Tests for Flask Blueprint gives attributeerror

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest, python-decorators

I'm writing tests for my application using unittest in Python3.6. I'm creating a simple Flask app for this test, that I want to register my defined blueprints with. The issue I get is when I try to import my blueprints is this one:

```
  File "/app/test/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import test_views
  File "/app/test/test_views.py", line 50, in <module>
    from api.metrics.views import stats
  File "/app/api/metrics/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .views import stats
  File "/app/api/metrics/views.py", line 13, in <module>
    def get_stats(client=None):
  File "/testenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/blueprints.py", line 161, in decorator
    endpoint = options.pop("endpoint", f.__name__)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 584, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __name__
```

The error comes where I call **@stats.route...** in this code:

```
stats = Blueprint('metrics', __name__)

@stats.route('/metrics', methods=['POST'])
@setup.require_suth
def get_metrics(client=None):
  <This code is not relevant>
```

Does anyone know how to do this correctly? I really can't figure out how to do this.

This is my structure:

```
/app
  /api 
     /metrics
       __init__.py
       views.py
  /test
       test_views.py
```

And here is the import statement in my tests:

```
app_ = define_test_app()
from api.metrics.views import stats
app_.register_blueprint(stats)
```

Would appreciate help, since I'm completely stuck at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Do NOT name the module, the directory and the blueprint with the same name.

Basically our code has this kind of constructs. subtree to make it simpler.

```
-- webcompat
   |-- __init__.py
   |-- form.py
   |-- api
   |   |-- __init__.py
   |   |-- uploads.py
   |   |-- endpoints.py
   …
   |-- helpers.py
   |-- views.py
```

so in `webcompat/__init__.py`

```py
from webcompat.api.endpoints import api
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
app.register_blueprint(api)
```

and in `webcompat/api/endpoints/__init__.py`

```py
from webcompat.helpers import cool_feature

api = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api')

@api.route('blah')
def somewhere(foo):
    """blablah"""
    yeah = cool_feature()
```

So what is happening here?
The module and the blueprint share the same name. So if in a test we need to mock cool_feature:

```py
with patch('webcompat.api.endpoints.cool_feature') as mock_cool:
```

We need to remember that when mocking, we do not mock the feature where it has been defined (aka `webcompat.helpers.cool_feature`) but where it has been imported (aka `webcompat.api.endpoints.cool_feature`). We will not be able to mock in this case because there will be a conflict of names. The error will be:

```
E    AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'endpoints'
```

because the named `webcompat.api` blueprint has no attribute `endpoints` while the module `webcompat.api` has one.

Comment: You are not _required_ to modify your original code for mocking if you have your blueprints set up this way; instead you can work around it with `patch.object()`. i.e. in your test code: `from webcompat.api import endpoints` and `with patch.object(endpoints, 'cool_feature') as mock_cool:`...

Answer (score 0):

You have an error when you call to register your blueprint, instead of `app_.register_blueprint` just use `app.register_blueprint`, try this one:

```
/app
  /api 
     /metrics
       __init__.py
       views.py
```

views.py

```
from flask import Blueprint

stats = Blueprint('metrics', __name__)


@stats.route('/metrics', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_metrics(client=None):
    return 'Hello'
```

---

```
/app
  /test
     test.py
```

test.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from api.metrics.views import stats
app.register_blueprint(stats)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```